# Native photo managment software for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, open-source, ubuntu, file-management, photography

I’m searching for picasa alike photo management software for Ubuntu. App should be native and I don’t want to run it in Wine or similar software. Don't mind if not included in Ubuntu repositories

**Important and necessary features**

- Fast downloading from camera cards
- Renaming (important to read date info from exif)
- Tagging (writing to exif)
- Ability to import photos respecting folder structure
- Easy rearranging folder structure
- Photo export function (picasa, flickr etc)

**Non-necessary but welcome features**

- Face recognition
- Minimal retouching function (aligning, red eye removal, colour
  enchantment)
- Watermark
- Ability to manipulate exif data (comments, tittle, publisher, owner
  etc)

Note I'm not searching for software to develop , enhance or post-process photography but simple an managing software.

Answer (score 5):

Both [shotwell](http://www.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/) and [f-spot](http://f-spot.org/) will basically do what you need here. Both have roughly equivalent feature sets, but I switch to shotwell after having too much trouble with f-spot crashing all the time.

Feature check:

- Fast downloading from camera cards (both)
- Renaming (important to read date info from exif) (both)
- Tagging (writing to exif) (both)
- Ability to import photos respecting folder structure (**no**)
- Easy rearranging folder structure (maybe)
- Photo export function (picasa, flickr etc) (both)
- Face recognition (unsure)
- Minimal retouching function (aligning, red eye removal, colour
  enchantment) (both)
- Watermark (unsure)
- Ability to manipulate exif data (comments, tittle, publisher, owner
  etc) (maybe)

You can compare the feature sets and screenshots here:

- [f-spot features](http://f-spot.org/Features)
- [shotwell features](http://www.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/)

As you can see, shotwell is a little more minimalist, but in turn is more stable. It is also bundle with Gnome and Ubuntu, if i remember correctly.

I should also mention [digiKam](http://www.digikam.org/), built for KDE.

Also note that higher-end development software like [darktable](https://www.darktable.org/) also have similar feature, but are much less intuitive as they have more usability problems. I nevertheless use darktable now because I do RAW/NEF development.

Comment: Shotwell version in Ubuntu repositories doesn't importing images by following folder structure. Once Photos are imported tool rearranges images on his own based on date taken. Not solution to manage 35K plus collection which is already sorted (lost days to return photos where I wanted 'em). Shotwell renaming actually ads comment to image but desn't rename images. Digikam tested too, takes in half KDE, and after initial import it just freeze. Darktable is excellent RAW developer but way to basic for my needs so not a good choice considering my growing collection. Still have to check F-spot.

Comment: Installed F-spot. Same as Shotwell makes own folders based on dates and doesn't respect existing folder structure, No rearranging folder structure option. No image renaming (description adding only). F-spot even requires mono to run. Uninstalled. Shotwell is better but still does not meet requirements.

Comment: Right, okay, I didn't understand that requirement well I guess. Note that darktable respects the hierarchy, but fails in other areas I believe.

Comment: yap Darktable is quite limited for photo managing, Shotwell so far nearest to what I my need my need to look deeper in it.